# XSLT How to delete all duplicated nodes when one field has duplicate values

Tags: xslt

I am new in XSLT need help, I want to remove all occurrences of **A_CustomerCompanyType**
node when **CompanyCode** has same duplicate value.

Need help.

Input

```
<A_CustomerCompany>
    <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075122</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>1051</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
    <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075122</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>1081</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
    <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075123</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>1051</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
    <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075123</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>3911</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
    <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075122</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>1041</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
</A_CustomerCompany>
```

Output

```
  <A_CustomerCompany>
     <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075122</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>1081</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
    <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075123</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>3911</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
    <A_CustomerCompanyType>
        <Customer>1075122</Customer>
        <CompanyCode>1041</CompanyCode>
    </A_CustomerCompanyType>
</A_CustomerCompany>
```

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes muenchian grouping is an option to group, I have done that but it keeps one of the nodes, but in my case I want to remove duplicate nodes. In my example companycode 1051 is repeated twice , I want that complete node to be deleted which contains companycode 1051.

Comment: For Muenchian grouping you declare a key, the items that are duplicates give `count(key('key-name', key-expression)) > 1)` or have `key('key-name', key-expression)[2]` so just stuff that into a predicate of an empty template: `<xsl:template match="A_CustomerCompanyType[key('key-name', CompanyCode)[2]]"/>`. Then the identity transformation templates copies the rest of the document.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your XSLT attempt.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Thanks it worked.